# Concat three strings from file when I find a match

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have this application where I read the contents of a .txt-file looking like this:

```
- ...
- Nonsense
- Nonsense
- Nonsense
- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3
- Nonsense
- Nonsense
- Line1
- Line2
- Line3 
- Nonsense
- ... etc
```

When I find the matching word "Line 1" I need to add the following two lines so i get the following result

```
- Line1 Line2 Line3
- Line1 Line2 Line3
```

I use a streamreader and a list to get the row for the first value but what is best practice to merge the following two lines? 
My code so far:

```
List<string> match = new List<string>();
string line;        

using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(txtInput))
        {
            while ((line = inputStream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("Line1"))
                {
                    match.Add(line);                        
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, couldn't you use `match.Add(line + " " + inputStream.ReadLine() + " " + inputStream.ReadLine())` to append the second and third line onto the first?

Comment: Yeah. I think that will do.

Comment: @Patrik - I assume the lines don't actually start with `- `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing your while loop like this will solve your issue.

```
while ((line = inputStream.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string outputLine;
                        if (line.Contains("Line1"))
                        {

                            outputLine = line + inputStream.ReadLine() + inputStream.ReadLine();
                            match.Add(outputLine);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you install Microsoft's Interactive Framework (NuGet "System.Interactive") then you get a handy `IEnumerable<T>` extension called `Buffer`. It'll let you do this:

```
List<string> match =
    File
        .ReadLines(txtInput)
        .Buffer(3, 1)
        .Where(x => x[0] == "Line1")
        .Select(x => String.Join(" ", x))
        .ToList();
```

That's it. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using a `StreamReader`. If you use `File.ReadAllLines()` you can iterate through your text file content alot easier. And you can check if there are 2 following lines after "Line1" as well a lot easier.

Something like this

```
var path = Path to the file;
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
List<string> matches = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];
    if(line.Equals("Line1"))
    {
        if (lines.Count > i + 2)
        {
            matches.Add(lines[i++]);
            matches.Add(lines[i++]);
            matches.Add(lines[i++]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution but its fragile and error prone. 1) If the text is very long, storing it all in memory with `ReadAllLines` is wasteful and could even lead to an `OutOfMemory` exception; consider unsing `ReadLines`. 2) What happens if the input is malformed and the file ends in "line 2"? Also, why are you creating a `List<string>`? The array returned by `ReadAllLines` would work just as well.

Comment: That's why I added the check `if (lines.Count > i + 2)`. If the text files are getting really big this won't be the best solution; yes. But even a text file with 10 million signs isn't bigger then 10 mb. So I guess the questioner would have said if he has to handle really big files.

Comment: Woops, sorry missed the check.

Answer (score 0):

Using C# 7's local functions syntax (not that its necessary by any means), you could do the following:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ProcessText(string txtInput)
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetNextNLines(IEnumerator<string> enumerator, int n)
    {
        var counter = 0;

        while (counter < n && enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
             yield return enumerator.Current;
             counter += 1;
        }

        if (counter != n) //consider throwing with an unexpected format message.
    }

    using (var enumerator = File.ReadLines(txtInput).GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (enumerator.Current.Constains("Line1"))
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;

                foreach (var line in GetNextNLines(enumerator, 2)
                {
                    yield return line;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is lazy and will avoid reading the whole file upfront, which can lead to problems if its very large.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you want a list of concatenated strings, with each string being a concatenation of 3 lines including `Line 1` and the next to. To do it using a stream reader and with slight modifications to your code:

```
 List<string> match = new List<string>();
 string line;

 using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(txtInput))
 {
     int charctersLeftAfterMatch = -1;
     string temp = "";
     while ((line = inputStream.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         // If first instance is found, update characters to pick up next 2
         if (line.Contains("Line1") || line.Contains("Line 1"))
         {
              charctersLeftAfterMatch = 3;
              temp = "";
         }

         // If last line (3rd) has been reached then add to collection
         // Else if lines are still left then concatenate and move ahead
         if (charctersLeftAfterMatch-- == 1)
         {
              temp += line;
              match.Add(temp);
         }
         else if (charctersLeftAfterMatch > 0)
         {
              temp += line;
         }
     }
}

// Match contains 2 string's: 
// [0] Line 1 Line 2 Line 3
// [1] Line1 Line2 Line3
```

Also, do note that you have `Line 1` in the first case and `Line1` the next time. If modified the `.Contains()` condition to take both into account.